# Unity Component is referencing the same gameObject instead of itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having this problem where when I instantiate multiple objects at once, the `gameObject` references the same instance on all objects whereas they should instead reference the gameObject that component is attached to.

So, I have this `MonoBehaviour`, which is the main part of my code. When the awake function runs it should create an instance of each `BootstrapMacro` so I don't overwrite the data in the `.asset` file (Which happens without this part).

Then in the new instance, I set a reference to the current `Bootstrap` component.

```
public class Bootstrap : MonoBehaviour {

  [SerializeField] List<BootstrapMacro> macros;
  public List<BootstrapMacro> runtimeMacros = new List<BootstrapMacro>();

  void Awake() {
    // Create a runtime version of the macro so to not overwrite the original asset file
    macros.ForEach(macro => {
      if (macro != null) {
        var mac = Instantiate(macro);
        mac.events.ForEach(evt => {
          evt.bootstrap = this;
          evt.actions.ForEach(act => { act.bootstrap = this; });
        });
        runtimeMacros.Add(mac);
      }
    });
    RunMacro(e => e.OnObjectAwake());
  }

  void Start() { RunMacro(e => e.OnObjectStart()); }

  void RunMacro(System.Action<BootstrapEvent> action) {
    runtimeMacros.ForEach(macro => {
      if (macro == null) return;
      macro.events.ForEach(evt => {
        if (!evt.enabled) return;
        action.Invoke(evt);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

My `BootstrapMacro` file is really basic:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Bootstrap Macro.asset", menuName = "Boostrap/Macro")]
public class BootstrapMacro : ScriptableObject {
  public List<Bootstrap.BootstrapEvent> events = new List<Bootstrap.BootstrapEvent>();
}
```

Then the event looks like this:

```
[BootstrapEvent(0)]
public class OnCreate : BootstrapEvent {
  public override void OnObjectStart() {
    Debug.Log(bootstrap.gameObject.name);
    Trigger();
  }
}
```

Which extends this:

```
public class BootstrapEvent : ScriptableObject {

  Bootstrap _bootstrap;

  public Bootstrap bootstrap {
    get { return _bootstrap; }
    set { if (_bootstrap == null) _bootstrap = value; }
  }

  public virtual void OnObjectStart() { }
}
```

I am instantiating the objects like this:

```
var o = Instantiate(_gameObject, _position, Quaternion.identity);
o.name = Random.Range(0, 1000).ToString();
```

So it is creating the object and giving it a random number. So when it is created I log the name as seen above (code block 3). However, they are all referencing the first object created....

So, what is causing the items to reference the same gameObject?

From the following picture what is happening is the `Debug.Log` is printing, the object name. As seen there are multiple object names getting printed. A new object name is written to the console every time the previous one is destroyed.

[image: Wrong References]

### Edit

So, It looks like the issue is with my property. If I remove `if(_bootstrap == null)`, then the code works as expected. If I leave it, it is using the first created item as the reference until it is destroyed then the next create item becomes the reference. Why?

```
  public Bootstrap bootstrap {
    get { return _bootstrap; }
    set { _bootstrap = value; }
  }
```

Comment: it is quite hard to imagine what this code is doing because it is too abstract but how do you know they are the same objects? only comparing the names?

Comment: I have a destroy command, on all the created objects, `Destroy(bootstrap.gameObject, 2f);`, and only one gets destroyed.

Comment: I have a feeling that it has to do with the way that the asset is instantiated, however I am not sure...

Comment: Might you be losing your references to the instantiated objects since you are creating local references to them inside your ForEach loop?  When `mac` goes out of scope you lose your reference.

Comment: @jiveturkey, why would mac go out of scope? it there in the list

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I was just checking `Instantiate` method. I can not test right now, but if you are not instantiating a brand new object from prefab, does it only create a shallow copy? I know for a fact that if you instantiate from prefabs, they are completely new objects but in the case of actively cloning an object, I can not say for sure

Comment: @EmrahSüngü It seems to make a deep copy, because the list works, and same with the child list of `BootstrapEvent`, It it just referencing the wrong gameobject at run time.

Comment: After doing a test where I debug `evt.bootstrap` before I assign it in the `forEach`, I would expect the value to be `null`. However, this is not the case it is only sometimes `null` otherwise it is the value of the last instance until it is destroyed then it is `null` again. To me this says that the `get/set` are being saved globally...

Comment: Okay, so removing the `if(_bootstrap == null)` and leaving the `_bootstrap = value` fixed the issue. Why?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I made an update with the issue. Is there a way for me to use what I have without removing the if? I only want to set the field `_bootstrap` once.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I was just doing tests now. Will repeat with `if(_bootstrap == null) and leaving the _bootstrap = value fixed the issue. ` Is bootstrap an asset on the store?

Comment: No, bootstrap is my personal asset

Comment: if u have destroy on each element have you tried `Destroy(this.gameObject, 2f);`

Comment: Destroy is on a `ScriptableObject`, so I don't have access to `this.gameObject`

Comment: ` evt.bootstrap = this;` is the only line where I see that `bootstrap` is set ... is it possible that multiple `Boostrap.macros` lists share the same references and therefore overwrite the same bootstrap value?

Answer (score -1):

```
var o = Instantiate(_gameObject, _position, Quaternion.identity);
o.name = Random.Range(0, 1000).ToString();
```

"So, what is causing the items to reference the same gameObject?"

`_gameObject` is your object reference, all of your `var o` objects are clones of this. this is the desired behavior with instantiation.

Note that if `_gameObject` gets destroyed, `var o` will no longer have a reference, and you will crash. that's why we use prefabs. they cant be removed from the scene so your reference wont go null.

Comment: I don't think that the instantiation is the issue.

Comment: I just made a test. Even if you Instantiate a gameobject, not a prefab, and destroy the original, the clone stays

Comment: yes the clone remains, but you can no longer use the original object to instantiate new objects, you will get a null pointer.